# Is it possible to create a vertical space mid-sentence?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing

I would like to center the links in the middle of the title (Pomodoro, Duelr). What's the best way to go about this? My code looks like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X r}
    \rule{0pt}{17pt}
    \hspace{-0.2em}\large\textbf{\textsc{Pomodoro} \vspace{0.5em} \href{https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Pomodoro}{\fontsize{7}{8.4}\selectfont - https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Pomodoro}} & \textit{May 2017}
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{-1.60em}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item A productivity-oriented web application which incentivizes the Pomodoro Technique via a reward system
    \item Features a dynamic leaderboard, responsive design, and user authentication with support for social accounts
    \item Deployed onto Heroku and built using Django/Python, HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap, JavaScript, jQuery, and AJAX
\end{itemize}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X r}
    \rule{0pt}{17pt}
    \hspace{-0.2em}\large\textbf{\textsc{Duelr} \href{https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Duelr}{\fontsize{7}{8.4}\selectfont - https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Duelr}} & \textit{Jun. 2017}
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{-1.60em}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item Duelr is an online multiplayer 1v1 fighting game which uses web sockets to deliver real-time interactions
    \item Features fluid character animations, intuitive controls, and fully functional collision mechanisms
    \item Hosted on Microsoft Azure and built with JavaScript, Node.js, Express.js, Socket.io, HTML5, CSS, and Phaser
\end{itemize}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: it would be much easier to answer if you provided an example that produced the image you show. But the question is not clear you ask for vertical space but say you want to centre the links, which would require adding horizontal space?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes it's possible. (E.g. putting the url inside a vbox… or there may be packages for it. I haven't worked out the details but it should be straightforward.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My bad. I don't want to center them horizontally, I want to center them vertically relative to the titles (ex. Pomodoro and Duelr)

Comment: oh you mean raise them by (around) half a baseline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to raise the url as below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand\midl[1]{\raisebox{1pt}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\sffamily

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X r}
    \rule{0pt}{17pt}
    \hspace{-0.2em}\large\textbf{%
\textsc{Pomodoro}
\midl{\href{https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Pomodoro}{\fontsize{7}{8.4}\selectfont - https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Pomodoro}}} & \textit{May 2017}
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{-1.60em}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item A productivity-oriented web application which incentivizes the Pomodoro Technique via a reward system
    \item Features a dynamic leaderboard, responsive design, and user authentication with support for social accounts
    \item Deployed onto Heroku and built using Django/Python, HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap, JavaScript, jQuery, and AJAX
\end{itemize}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X r}
    \rule{0pt}{17pt}
    \hspace{-0.2em}\large\textbf{%
\textsc{Duelr}
\midl{\href{https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Duelr}{\fontsize{7}{8.4}\selectfont - https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Duelr}}} & \textit{Jun. 2017}
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{-1.60em}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item Duelr is an online multiplayer 1v1 fighting game which uses web sockets to deliver real-time interactions
    \item Features fluid character animations, intuitive controls, and fully functional collision mechanisms
    \item Hosted on Microsoft Azure and built with JavaScript, Node.js, Express.js, Socket.io, HTML5, CSS, and Phaser
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\raisebox` and calculate the height it has to be risen:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newdimen\mytitlehtONE
\newdimen\mytitlehtTWO

\newcommand{\mytitle}[2]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\large\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}%
    \mytitlehtONE=\ht0%
    \setbox0\hbox{\textbf{\href{#2}{\fontsize{7}{8.4}\selectfont - #2}}}%
    \mytitlehtTWO=\ht0%
    \advance\mytitlehtONE by -\mytitlehtTWO\relax%
    \hspace{-0.2em}\fbox{\large\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}
    \raisebox{0.5\mytitlehtTWO}{\unhbox0}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X r}
    \rule{0pt}{17pt}
    \mytitle{Pomodoro}{https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Pomodoro} & \textit{May 2017}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

It results in:
[image]

The `\fbox` is just to show that it is really the middle of the line. Without it the command is:

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}[2]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\large\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}%
    \mytitlehtONE=\ht0%
    \setbox0\hbox{\textbf{\href{#2}{\fontsize{7}{8.4}\selectfont - #2}}}%
    \mytitlehtTWO=\ht0%
    \advance\mytitlehtONE by -\mytitlehtTWO\relax%
    \hspace{-0.2em}\large\textbf{\textsc{#1}}
    \raisebox{0.5\mytitlehtTWO}{\unhbox0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: centering along the math axis.  This has the advantage that it automatically scales to different sizes without requiring to measure a temporary box; it has the downside that it needs a bit of low-level TeX coding.

[image: Output of the following code]

The source code follows.  I’ve also cleaned it up in several points.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment*{myList}[3]{%
    {\noindent \parfillskip\z@skip
        \rule{0pt}{17pt}% <-- !!! (But why this rule?)
        % \hspace{-0.2em} % no longer necessary, I guess! ;-)
        {\large
            {%
                \bfseries
                % \scshape % not supported
                #1\/%
            }%
            ~$\m@th \vcenter{\hbox{\scriptsize - \url{#2}}}$%
        }%
        \nobreak\hfill \textit{#3}\@@par
    }%
    % \vspace{-1.60em} % specify "nosep" instead of "noitemsep"
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]%
}{%
    \end{itemize}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\sffamily

\begin{myList}
        {Pomodoro}
        {https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Pomodoro}
        {May 2017}

    \item
        A productivity-oriented web application which incentivizes the Pomodoro
        Technique via a reward system.

    \item
        Features a dynamic leaderboard, responsive design, and user
        authentication with support for social accounts.

    \item
        Deployed onto Heroku and built using Django/Python, HTML5, CSS\@,
        Bootstrap, JavaScript, jQuery, and AJAX\@. %"\@" for precaution
\end{myList}

\begin{myList}
        {Duelr}
        {https://www.GitHub.com/AllanMukundi/Duelr}
        {Jun. 2017}

    \item
        Duelr is an online multiplayer 1v1 fighting game which uses web sockets
        to deliver real-time interactions.

    \item
        Features fluid character animations, intuitive controls, and fully
        functional collision mechanisms.

    \item
        Hosted on Microsoft Azure and built with JavaScript, Node.js,
        Express.js, Socket.io, HTML5, CSS\@, and Phaser.
\end{myList}

\end{document}
```